# TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python-asyncio, flask-socketio

function i am trying to call from my flask-socketio server

```py
from flask_socketio import emit
import asyncio

async def myfunc():
     for i in range(10):
         j = 1*3
         await emit('update', {'j':j})
```

in my server function i am running

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
task = asyncio.gather(myfunc())
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

I am getting an error **on the 1st iteration of the loop** one successful emit.

```py
File "path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "path\to\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 636, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "path\to\lib\site-packages\socketio\server.py", line 665, in _trigger_event
    return self.handlers[namespace][event](*args)
  File "path\to\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 280, in _handler
    *args)
  File "path\to\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 694, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "path\to\server.py", line 127, in print_message
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "path\to\Python\Python37-32\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "path\to\script.py", line 261, in fun
    await emit('update', {'j':j})
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

I want to be able to call myfunc() and emit an update to my socketio client on each iteration of for loop

Answer (score 33):

I also got this same error when I called `await` on a `non async` function.

e.g.

```
def do_something():
    print("Do Something")

async erroneous_function():
    await do_something()
```

The solution is simple, remove the `await` in front of the `do_something()` since it's not async.

Answer (score 1):

Flask and Flask-SocketIO do not work with asyncio. Either remove the asyncio stuff, or else drop Flask and Flask-SocketIO and use python-socketio, which does have support for asyncio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Miguel. Which server framework can i use with asyncio? I was using aiohttp and was facing frequent crashes.

Comment: aiohttp is actually one of the best choices. There is also sanic and quart if you want to try something else.

Comment: quart is a compatible replacement for flask.

Comment: Also consider FastAPI.

Answer (score 0):

To future Django coders.  If you get this message in your Django Channels Consumer subclass, make sure the correct methods are marked as async:

```
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass
```

is the correct way.  Without the prefix async, I get the same above error, whenever my client calls closes() the WS conn.