# Error loading extension: Extension 'slash_commands.Staff_Moderation' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord.py bot in python using pycharm and i am trying to create a bot for my friend that he can use for moderation in his server, however whenever i try to load this extension i face this error

This is the code of Staff_Moderation.py:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


logging = True
bot_logs = 1201809195738083360


class StaffModeration(app_commands.Group):
    @app_commands.command(name='mute')
    @commands.has_role('Staff')
    async def mute(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member, reason: str):
        if interaction.user.guild_permissions.mute_members:
            await member.edit(mute=True, reason=reason)

            if not reason:
                await member.send(f'Muted by {interaction.user} for reason: {reason}')
            else:
                await member.send(f'Muted by {interaction.user}')

            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Muted {member.mention} for reason: {reason}', ephemeral=True)

    @app_commands.command(name='kick')
    async def kick(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
        if interaction.user.guild_permissions.kick_members:
            await member.kick()
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Kicked {member.mention}!')


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.tree.add_command(StaffModeration(name='staff', description='Used for moderation'))
```

This is my main.py:

```
import logging
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
GUILD_ID = int(getenv("GUILD_ID"))
WELCOME_CHANNEL = int(getenv("WELCOME_CHANNEL"))

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
COGS_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'cogs'
SLASH_COMMANDS_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'slash_commands'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,
                    filename='logs/logs.txt',
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y'
                    )


# Loads all responses/commands of bot
async def start_bot(bot):
    try:
        # Loads every file in cogs directory which is not an __init__.py file
        for cogs in COGS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
            if cogs.name != "__init__.py":
                await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cogs.name[:-3]}')

        # Loads every slash command in slash_command DIR which is not an __init__.py file
        for slash_cmds in SLASH_COMMANDS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
            if slash_cmds.name != "__init__.py":
                await bot.load_extension(f'slash_commands.{slash_cmds.name[:-3]}')

        print('Bot is ready')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error loading extension: {e}')


def run_bot():
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="'", intents=discord.Intents.all())

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        await bot.tree.sync()
        bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=discord.Object(GUILD_ID))

        print(f"Logged in as {bot.user} with ID {bot.user.id} in guild, {bot.guilds[0].id}")
        await start_bot(bot)
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing), status=discord.Status.idle)

    @bot.event
    async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandError):
            logging.error(f'Error in command {ctx.command}: {error}\n'
                          '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        welcome_channel_id = WELCOME_CHANNEL

        # Get the welcome channel
        welcome_channel = member.guild.get_channel(welcome_channel_id)

        if welcome_channel:
            # Send a welcome message
            await welcome_channel.send(f'Welcome to the server, {member.mention}!\n'
                                       f'You joined on {datetime.now().strftime('%c')}\n'
                                       'bOnk')

    bot.run(TOKEN)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_bot()
```

Traceback Error:-

```
01/31/2024:INFO:logging in using static token
01/31/2024:INFO:Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 30378396537cc050283fe7d7f8d4dc8d).
01/31/2024:ERROR:Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\boyfa\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 947, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\boyfa\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\boyfa\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\main.py", line 55, in on_ready
    await start_bot(bot)
  File "C:\Users\boyfa\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\main.py", line 38, in start_bot
    await bot.load_extension(f'slash_commands.{slash_cmds.name[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\boyfa\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1013, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\boyfa\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\Discord Bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 952, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'slash_commands.Staff_Moderation' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

This is my directory tree [Directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVLBs.png)

Tried to remove await from every message and did not work.
Tried removing async from setup function and no result.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't clear what is the issue; but, try checking what ```slash_cmds.name[:-3]``` is.  Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872323/typeerror-object-nonetype-cant-be-used-in-await-expression to see if it applies to you.

Comment: @ewokx that basically loads all the slash commands that I have created. It's the same thing I use for cogs and it works so I highly doubt this is the giving the error

Comment: Try listing all the slash commands you've created and check if that ```name[:-3]``` exists.   Take a look at all those  files in ```SLASH_COMMANDS_DIR/slash_commands``` and see which one is bad.  Since I have no way of testing anything, you could remove all but one and see if it runs.  If it runs, then there must be a slash_command file that's bad in someway.

Comment: @ewokx i only have this file in the directory, but ill try loading the file outside the for loop if it fixes it

Comment: You have just one file?  What does it look like?

Comment: @ewokx I added my directory tree so that you can understand it better

Comment: Might https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102943/await-client-load-extension-gives-await-error-with-nonetype help?

Comment: @ewokx nope. It did not sadly. I tried manually loading the extension and it gave the same error

Comment: @ewokx I FIGURED IT OUT. I manually imported the file and added my tree command in my on_ready function and it worked!. My guess now is that whenever we use the load_extension command it automatically converts the setup into an aync function(which breaks the code and hence does not work). Also you do not need to await the bot.tree.add_command so thats why it was breaking